# points on non-hyperelliptic curves of genus 3

Tags: arithmetic-geometry

I have a non-hyperelliptic curve $C$ of genus 3 and I'm interested in finding the $K$-rational points on the curve with $K$ a fixed imaginary quadratic number field.

As $C$ is a non-hyperelliptic genus 3 curve, the Jacobian $J_C(\mathbb{Q})$ of $C$ cannot be computed directly in any current computer algebra system that I know of. I'm wondering if somebody would point me to the state of art so that I can figure out if $J_C(\mathbb{Q})$ can be determined.

Comment: Writing the equation of the curve would help a lot. If it has e.g. CM then there would be more tricks available.

Comment: The paper [Generalized explicit descent and its applications to genus 3 curves](http://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/genus3.pdf), published in Forum of Math. Sigma in 2016, by Nils Bruin, Bjorn Poonen, and Michael Stoll gives a procedure for doing descent on the Jacobian of a genus 3 curve.